# Java: How to read "Files of type" in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to create a new file while file type is choosing by the user on JFileChooser. How this is possible. I use this code for JFileChooser:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setDialogTitle("Save data in your file format");

FileFilter type1 = new ExtensionFilter("Access 2007 Database(*.accdb)", ".accdb");
FileFilter type2 = new ExtensionFilter("Access 2002-2003 Database(*.mdb)", ".mdb");

chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(type1);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(type2);

int actionDialog = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
```

Now I an able to get the "File Name" when the user select any file by this code:

```
 chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
```

**But I dont know how to get "Files of type" when user select any file.**
For the convenience I also attach photo of JFileChooser:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save file using JFileChooser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531037/how-to-save-file-using-jfilechooser)

Comment: sorry if this question is duplicated.

Comment: No worries. I would recommend you take a look since that question is the same that you are asking.

Comment: doesn't `getFileFilter()` method help??

Comment: its give the things in this way: com.xxx.filechooser.ExtensionFilter@1eb904d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information using `JFileChooser .getFileFilter()`

[From the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getFileFilter%28%29):

> *Returns the currently selected file filter*

Comment: I use as mention by you to print on console by using this code: System.out.println(chooser.getFileFilter().toString());
but it print like this: com.xxx.filechooser.ExtensionFilter@1eb904d

Comment: @VinitVikash: That's the output of the default `toString()` implenetation, nothing wrong with that. Please read the Javadocs for `FileFilter` and `ExtensionFileFilter`