# How can i save .txt file at desired location using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser, java-io

Using following code i can store program.txt in a working project folder, but how can I use JFileChooser or any other option to save file at a selected location?

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {

                o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("program.txt"));

                o.write(t1.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t2.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t3.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t4.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t5.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t6.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.write(t7.getText());
                o.write(",");
                o.close();


            }
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save file using JFileChooser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531037/how-to-save-file-using-jfilechooser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(aComponent); //parent component to JFileChooser
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //OK button pressed by user
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile(); //get File selected by user
        o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); //use its name

        ...
        //your writing code goes here
}
```

Comment: i want user to create a file and then write on it.

Comment: @user2003602 I have changed to `showSaveDialog` then `FileWriter` would create file.

Comment: still not working :-( , i can compile it without error but it is not creating any file

Comment: @user2003602 Replace `o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getName()));` with `o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));`, otherwise the file will be written in the working directory.

Comment: @user2003602 Btw, using FileWriter often leads to encoding problems because it uses the default system encoding. I would rather use the good-old-fashioned way with a FileOutputStream encapsulated in a BufferedOutputStream and convert String to bytes using `getBytes(encoding)`

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov please update your answer to correct it because as it stands it contains major flaws

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way by setting File object in JFileChooser object

```
File f = new File("filename");
myJFileChooser.setSelectedFile(f);
```

check this post for more

http://www.coderanch.com/t/561950/GUI/java/Save-JTextArea-JFileChooser-TXT-file

Comment: `File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));` would be better.  But then, I think that is the default for `JFileChooser` in any case.