# How to save an excel file with .xls extension in java?

Tags: java, excel

I have to save an excel file with .xls extension.I want that the extension should be taken by default as soon as I select the file type in save file dialog box designed using file chooser.I have tried this much of code but it is saving the file in .xls format only when I give the file name as filename.xls

```
public void FileSave() throws IOException{             

   JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser(".");       
   FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel files","xls","excel");       
   chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);      
   chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
   chooser.setFileSelectionMode(chooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
   chooser.setDialogTitle("Save File");
   chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home")));
   chooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter(){
        public boolean accept(final File f){
            return f.isDirectory()|| file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xls");
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return "Excel files (*.xls)";
        }
  });

  int returnVal1=chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
  if (returnVal1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        file1 = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        if(!file1.exists()){
            FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(file1);
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("\n Your Excel file has been generated!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"File Created.");
        }
        else if(file1.exists()){
            int res=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"File already exists.Do you wish to overwrite?");
            if(res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(file1);
                hwb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
                System.out.println("\n Your Excel file has been generated!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"File Created.");
            }else if(res == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                int returnVal2=chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
                if (returnVal2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                    File file2 = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    if(!file2.exists()){

                        FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(file2);
                        hwb.write(fileOut);
                        fileOut.close();
                        System.out.println("\n Your Excel file has been generated!");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"File Created.");
                    }

                }
            }else if (res == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "User cancelled operation.");
            } 
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010647/set-default-saving-extention-with-jfilechooser

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this option to set the file name as *.xls:

```
chooser.setSelectedFile("*.xls");
```

And for the File type dropdown, set the below options:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel files","xls","excel");       
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);     
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.

```
if(!file1.exists())
{
           FileOutputStream fileOut =  new   FileOutputStream(file1+".xls");
           hwb.write(fileOut);
           fileOut.close();
           System.out.println("\n Your Excel file has been generated!");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"File Created.");
}
```